# Linux and thunderbolt: insmod always returns "function not implemented"

Tags: linux, thunderbolt

I have a Linux machine (running kernel 4.9.84 on Debian stretch) with a thunderbold card, supported by the thunderbolt driver:

```
# lspci -s 09:00.0 -k
09:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL5320 Thunderbolt 2 NHI [Falcon Ridge 2C 2013]
        Kernel modules: thunderbolt
```

However, the thunderbolt module doesn't load, and can't be loaded:

```
# modprobe thunderbolt 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'thunderbolt': Function not implemented
```

No message in `dmesg` or else. Bizarrely, if I run this `insmod` on any machine at hand, running Slackware, Debian, Ubuntu, with different kernels ranging from 4.4 to 4.9, all replies exactly the same: "Function not implemented". On a VM with a 4.14 kernel, however, `modprobe thunderbolt` seems to work fine. I don't understand, what's happening?

Comment: https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.13#Thunderbolt . You could try a newer kernel on the host then (eg today on Debian, there's stretch-backports providing linux-image-4.16.0-0.bpo.2-amd64)

Comment: @A.B yes, I've installed 4.13. I can't run anything higher than 4.13 because of a very annoying bug with aacraid that would even prevent this machine from booting. Thunderbolt loaded OK. Now I wonder how to see the connected hard drive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some more details by reading the kernel documentation:
Thunderbolt requires that you manually authorize your devices. However no utility exists in current distributions for that. You can either try compiling yourself the `tbtadm` utility found here:
https://github.com/intel/thunderbolt-software-user-space

Or go the unsafe way as [described in the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/thunderbolt.html):

*Those users who just want to connect any device without any sort of manual work, can add following line to /etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules:*

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="thunderbolt", ATTR{authorized}=="0", ATTR{authorized}="1"
```

*This will authorize all devices automatically when they appear. However, keep in mind that this bypasses the security levels and makes the system vulnerable to DMA attacks.*

Now I see the hard drive on the bus as described in the documentation:

```
# cat /sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-1/*_name
8big Rack Thunderbolt 2
LaCie
```

Looking at lspci output I find it here:

```
0c:00.0 RAID bus controller: Device 1c19:0001 (rev b3)
```

So it's a RAID controller of some sort, that must require a driver (which one? Is it available for Linux? Who knows).

By digging into the Windows driver, I determined that it must be using a Marvell RAID controller. Now I need to find which one, and if a Linux driver exists, then try patching the driver by adding the PCI id 1c19:0001 in the supported ones. Sounds fun :) Let's try `mvsas` first...